# KSZ8863MLL issue - suggestions on resolving

Tags: ethernet

I have a NXP K64 cpu connected to a KSZ8863MLL (two port Ethernet switch) operating in MII mode.

I built 10 boards -- 9 work.

The board that does not work properly behaves as follows (testing using JTAG)

When K64 is in reset - KSZ8863MLL operates (network leds and activity leds active).

In the K64's EMAC code setup, the K64 pins are mapped into MII mode.

When K64 pin MMI0_TXD2 is set to MMI mode - the pin goes from a floating input (3.3v on scope) to GND as the pin becomes an output.

At the conclusion of executing THAT pin's related instruction - all LEDS on the KSZ8863MLL go out and the device becomes inactive.

Programming all other MMI related pins on the K64 have expected results.

I have looked at the board under an inspection microscope and found no trace/solder issues.

I have scoped adjacent PCB traces to see if an internal PCB layer may have shorted traces (PCB is 4 layer) -- no change to adjacent traces found when pin goes from input to output.

I have placed a break point after the instruction to make sure other code was not executing and to isolate the KSZ8863MLL behavior to just that single instruction.

I've narrowed it to that single pin - going from input (pin at 3.3v) to output (pin a GND) that causes the KSZ8863MLL to stop operating.

I'm lost as were to look/proceed further.  As stated earlier -- 9 other boards work perfectly which suggest the issue is related to parts/assembly of this specific board.

The KSZ8863MLL appears to be OK since it shows activity as long as the K644 has not set that pin's mode to MMI.

The 3 other related TX pins (TX0, TX1, TX3) all go from 3.3v to GND when their mode is switched to MMI.

Any insight or suggestions?

Comment: wirebond fracture? use coldspray/heat

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this applies without a full schematic and chip specs, but you need to be careful with IO operations like this if the receiver of the IO pin is edge detecting.

I have had issues in the past when toggling an output pin, especially when it's a change from input to output or vica-versa, where a race condition occurs during the change.

When that happens you can generate a very small (nS) pulse on the pin that you won't notice on the scope. However, some receiving devices MAY see it as a clock edge on the signal. Others may not.

It can be a real head scratcher to figure out.

May not be your problem, but it is somewhere to look if everything else is proven to be working nominally.

BTW: If it is the latter, something like switching a couple of lines of code can often fix it. If not you may need to make the signal synchronous instead of asynchronous.